# Why there is a negative sign on the gravitation formula?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electrostatics, newtonian-gravity, vectors, conventions

It all started when I was coding some simulation of the Newton's Law of Gravitation and Culomb's Law.

When I was seeking  information on the internet, I found out that some people wrote this formulas like this:
$$F = G \frac{m_1m_2}{r^2}\widehat{r}$$
$$F = -K \frac{q_1q_2}{r^2}\widehat{r}$$
This formulae make sense to me, because if you find the normal vector  of direction, $\widehat{r}$; in the case of the gravity, the force will be proportional to this $\widehat{r}$ and in the case of electric charges it also will be proportional to $\widehat{r}$ but in negative (and that's why we have the negative sign in front of the formula), because it is a repulsive force (correct me if I'm wrong)

**For Example:** In this case the direction vector occurs to be like this.
[image: ex]

As mentioned before, the gravitational force will be multiplied by this direction vector and will give its components. In the case of the electrostatic force, is the same but in negative.

**But:**

This are the formulae that don't make sense to me:
$$F = -G \frac{m_1m_2}{r^2}\widehat{r}$$
$$F = K \frac{q_1q_2}{r^2}\widehat{r}$$
They are the same, but with opposite signs.

**For Example:**
If you try to find the direction vector of A to B:
[image: AB]
Which in this case is $\widehat{AB} = \Bigg \langle \frac{3\sqrt{13}}{13}, \frac{2\sqrt{13}}{13}\Bigg \rangle$

and $\widehat{BA} = \Bigg \langle -\frac{3\sqrt{13}}{13}, -\frac{2\sqrt{13}}{13}\Bigg \rangle$

If you multiply this normalized vectors, by this new formulas, to get the force to be applied in each axes, you will get repulsion force in the case of gravity and an attraction forces (in case of same sign charges) in the electrostatics because of this change in the signs.

So my question is... ¿Which formula is the "good one"? If there is one.
¿What are the differences? Using analytic geometry, ¿which is better and more useful to make calculation with?

**Note:** I'm assuming the typical cartesian coordinates. In the X axes: to the right, positive, to the left, negative. In the Y axes: up is positive, down is negative.

Comment: It's not clear what your question is actually asking. You have to make a choice of which direction you are calling the "positive" direction. If you're hoping to model gravity (or electrostatics) with Newton and Coulomb's laws you cannot simply insert a minus sign because you will predict that things move in the opposite direction to how they do in real life.

Comment: This is why I was asking, because I found this formulae that added or removed the signs randonmly (in my opinion).

Comment: I was assuming the typical cartesian coordinates. In the X axes, to the right, positive, to the left, negative. In the Y axes, up is positive, down is negative.

Comment: This again just depends on which direction you consider the "positive direction".

Comment: You can't arbitrarily assign a sign to the Coulomb equation.  Like charges repel (both positive and negative like charges) and opposite charges attract.  Your code will have to determine whether there is attraction or repulsion at run time.

Comment: Which some people?

Answer (score 1):

This is just according to different definitions of $\hat r$.

In the first pair of formulas $\hat r$ is the unit vector from one object to the other, so an attractive force is positive. In the second pair of formulas $\hat r$ is the spherical coordinate basis vector in the (outward) radial direction, so an attractive force is negative.

There is nothing more to it than that. The definition of $\hat r$ and whether the force is attractive or repulsive determines the sign. Both pairs of formulas are valid

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, the magnitude of the force, $ |F| $ is:

$$ G\frac{m_1 m_2}{r^2} $$

The sign is just related to the vector direction and your choice of axis.

In your picture, you can choose a coordinate axis denoted by  $\widehat{r} $ and, let's say, $ \widehat{s} $ in the following way (please, ignore the small angles between your force lines and my axis line and imagine the force vectors are over the $ r $ axis):

[image]

In that case, the gravitational force on the particle at the origin produced by the other particle is in the positive direction of the axis and therefore:

$$ G\frac{m_1 m_2}{r^2} \widehat{r} $$

However, the direction of the gravitational force on the other particle, produced by the particle at the origin is in the opposite direction to your choice of positive axis. And therefore:

$$ G\frac{m_1 m_2}{r^2} (-\widehat{r}) = -G\frac{m_1 m_2}{r^2} \widehat{r} $$